# establish_connection doesn't bring over model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multiple-databases

Issue: I have multiple databases that I have to connect to depending on the server that is chosen from the start. If I have a client table that has an association of userclasses, I can connect to one of the databases fine and query clients, but if I do `@clients.userclasses` I get an error saying that the table userclasses doesn't exist because its reverting back to the original database.

Code below:

```
class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end

class Client < Connection
  has_many :userclasses, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Userclass < Connection
  belongs_to :client
  self.table_name = "userclasses"
end

class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_server
  def show
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html{ render html: @client}
      format.xml { render xml: @client }
    end
  end
  private

  def set_server
    @server = Server.find(params[:server_id])
    unless @server.nil? or @server.database.nil?
      Client.establish_connection(ActiveRecord::Base.configurations["#{@server.database}"])
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just switching the entire ActiveRecord connection to the one I needed, instead of trying to switch just the model I was using.

```
def set_server
    @server = Server.find(params[:server_id])
    unless @server.nil? or @server.database.nil?
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(ActiveRecord::Base.configurations["#{@server.database}"])
    end
  end
```